# how to animate 100 circles using canvas and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a blackhole simulation that will display a blackhole and 100 circles travelling away from it at a speed that would be decreasing because of gravity. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>test trou noir</title>
 <script>
var canvas = document.getElementById ("space");
var ctx = canvas.getContext ('2d');
var blackhole;
var circle = new Array();

window.onload = init;

function init (){
var  G = 6.67e-11, //gravitational constant 
c = 3e8, //speed of light (m/s)
M = 12e31, // masseof the blackhole in kg (60 solar masses)  
Rs = (2 * G * M) / 9e16, //Schwarzchild radius 
    pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3;// scaled radius 

  blackhole = new Ball (pixel_Rs, 700, 400, "black");
  blackhole.draw ();
};

function Ball (radius, posX, posY, color){
 this.radius = radius;
  this.posX = posX;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.color = color;
} 
Ball.prototype.draw = function (ctx){
  var ctx = canvas.getContext ('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath ();
  ctx.arc (this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath ();
  ctx.fill();
};

  </script>
  <style>
     body {
    background-color:#021c36 ;
 margin: 0px;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id ="space", width = "1400", height = "800">
 </canvas>  
 </body>
  </html>
```

Can someone tell me why I can't make the canvas draw the blackhole and how to create those 100 circles and animate them, I have literally tried everything and I can't make it work 
Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you just don't see the blackhole because it doesn't emit light :) And possibly you need to add <canvas id="space"/> to the html body

Comment: for your canvas displaying the black arc you told it to draw, you need to have a canvas in your document, to wrap your script in an `onload` event, to remove the `ctx` in `blackhole.draw(ctx)` or to actually pass the calls a context2d, and you'll also have to make sure your canvas has its width and height attribute set to > 1000. For your moving circles, that's a too broad question for SO's format.

Comment: but i did put the canvas tag (I probably copy/pasted wrong) and I don't understand why it doesn't draw the black circle

Comment: Please check your console, `document.getElementById ("space");` and 
`canvas.getContext ('2d');` should be in the `init` function, or after your canvas declaration in the doc. Here it does draw the arc : https://jsfiddle.net/67051mec/

Comment: So after your edit, I can confirm that when you call it, canvas is null, and ctx is undefined.

Comment: so the problem is my canvas is undefined, therefore i don't have a place to draw the arc, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the canvas from your html:

```
<canvas id="space"/>
```

You need to pass ctx to your draw function:

```
blackhole.draw(ctx);
```

Though it still doesn't draw, but that might be because of the sizes/colors.

update:

Here's a version that you can see: https://jsfiddle.net/gjwh33mq/2/ From here you can gradually change the numbers. (There's some strange bug, the window.onload is not getting called, so I added a call at the end of the js)

Comment: what do you mean it might be because of the colours

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gjwh33mq/ I mean you probably draw to a point that's outside of the canvas size. And all those huge numbers.... Try to draw a small circle to a known place on the canvas, then start to change the numbers to the real phisics values. And you will probably need to scale some things here, 'cause you won't have enough canvas size IMHO

Comment: See my last update, you can even see your black hole there :)

Comment: @Gavriel, its actually around coordinates 800, 600 https://jsfiddle.net/67051mec/ canvas element is not self-closing, and you should set width and height attributes or it will default to 300, 150

Comment: yes, I managed to fix it too. window.onload wasn't called in jsfiddle for some reason

Comment: why did you get rid of the definition of the canvas and ctx variables?

Comment: I just moved them into init

Comment: one last question, should I create a new constructor for the 100 circles I want to animate and then animate them with a requestanimFrame function or should i use the same ball object, what would you recommend ?

Comment: If the exact same draw function will be used then use Ball.